# How to monitor every single command that's running in a bash file?

Tags: bash

For instance I have this file named **test.sh**:

```
sleep 2
pgrep wget
if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
echo "<font color=\"green\"><b>Wget is running right now</b></font>" > /www/wget_status.txt
else
echo "<font color=\"red\"><b>Wget is NOT running</b></font>" > /www/wget_status.txt
fi
pgrep openvpn
if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
echo "<font color=\"green\"><b>OpenVPN is running right now</b></font>" > /www/openvpn_status.txt
else
echo "<font color=\"red\"><b>OpenVPN is NOT running</b></font>" > /www/openvpn_status.txt
fi
elinks -auto-submit /www/web.html
```

How can I monitor every single command of that file? whether they're running well or not. If I type in `top` it just monitors the file not every command that is running inside that file. I hope you understand what I'm trying to ask here.

Comment: If I understand well, you can just execute `bash -x test.sh` and you will see the commands the script is executing.

Comment: You can also use "set -x" inside the bash script (or just in your shell) to do that.